# How can I create application that Support both mobile & tablet?

Tags: android

I want to create an application which support both mobile & tablet. In my application ABCD images which I disply using view. I wan't this application will be run on both mobile & tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the platform OS select your version.

For android select the version [lowest which runs in mobile]... Then it will run in TABLET also.

click right if you like my answer 
else please post your difficulties.

Answer (score 3):

please read following documentation for supporting multiple screens

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

from google docs

> To disable this version of screen compatibility mode, you simply need
>   to set android:minSdkVersion or android:targetSdkVersion to "4" or
>   higher, or set android:resizeable to "true".

use following for adding multiple screen support :

you should include the  element in your manifest file like shown on following link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html